# ReferenceError: next is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have Encomenda that has an array of Itens. Itens can have an array of itens.
I have the following code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var idvalidator = require('mongoose-id-validator');

let ItemSchema = new Schema({
    produtoId:Number,
    itens:[{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Item'}]
});

function autoPopulateItens(next){
    this.populate('itens');
    next();
}
ItemSchema
    .pre('findOne',autoPopulateItens)
    .pre('find',autoPopulateItens);


module.exports=mongoose.model('Item',ItemSchema);

let EncomendaSchema= new Schema({
    itens:[ItemSchema]
});

module.exports=mongoose.model('Encomenda',EncomendaSchema);


function log(data){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data,undefined,2))
}
```

And I'm trying to make a post request on postman to create an Encomenda with the following code:

```
{
    "itens":[{
        "produtoId":5,
        "itens":[{
            "produtoId":6,
            "itens":[]
        },{
            "produtoId":7,
            "itens":[]
        },{
            "produtoId":8,
            "itens":[]
        }]
    }
        ]
}
```

But when I try to create an Encomenda and save it to the mongodb it gives me an error:

```
  CoreMongooseArray [ { itens: [], _id: 5bd9fde20c29e35f2c0ca74a, produtoId: 5 } ]
ValidationError: Encomenda validation failed: itens.0.itens: Cast to Array failed for value "[ { produtoId: 6 },
  { produtoId: 7, itens: [] },
  { produtoId: 8, itens: [] } ]" at path "itens"
    at new ValidationError (D:\ISEP\3º\ARQSI\pr2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:30:11)
    at model.Document.invalidate (D:\ISEP\3º\ARQSI\pr2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2026:32)
    at EmbeddedDocument.invalidate (D:\ISEP\3º\ARQSI\pr2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\types\embedded.js:289:19)
    at EmbeddedDocument.$set (D:\ISEP\3º\ARQSI\pr2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:989:10)
    at EmbeddedDocument._handleIndex (D:\ISEP\3º\ARQSI\pr2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:773:14)
    at EmbeddedDocument.$set (D:\ISEP\3º\ARQSI\pr2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:719:22)
    at EmbeddedDocument.Document (D:\ISEP\3º\ARQSI\pr2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:115:12)
    at EmbeddedDocument [as constructor] (D:\ISEP\3º\ARQSI\pr2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\types\embedded.js:39:12)
    at new EmbeddedDocument (D:\ISEP\3º\ARQSI\pr2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\documentarray.js:75:17)
    at DocumentArray.cast (D:\ISEP\3º\ARQSI\pr2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\documentarray.js:334:22)
    at DocumentArray.SchemaType.applySetters (D:\ISEP\3º\ARQSI\pr2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:763:12)
    at model.$set (D:\ISEP\3º\ARQSI\pr2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:981:18)
    at model._handleIndex (D:\ISEP\3º\ARQSI\pr2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:773:14)
    at model.$set (D:\ISEP\3º\ARQSI\pr2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:719:22)
    at model.Document (D:\ISEP\3º\ARQSI\pr2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:115:12)
    at model.Model (D:\ISEP\3º\ARQSI\pr2\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:90:12)
```

this how I try to create and save an Encomenda:

```
exports.encomenda_create = function (req, res,next) {
    var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
    var client = new Client();

     let encomenda=new Encomenda(req.body);

    encomenda.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        res.send('encomenda criada com sucesso')
    })
};
```

Answer (score 6):

Pass `next` as a parameter into your function like so:

`exports.encomenda_create = function (req, res, next) {`